# Languages don't seem to work in vuejs-datepicker

Tags: vuejs-datepicker

Following exactly the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker)'s instructions on languages, I'm trying to display the date in German format. Instead I still see it in English: "12 Apr 2020".

Also tried in Spanish, still get "12 Apr 2020".

Am I missing something?

```
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker'
import {en, de} from 'vuejs-datepicker/dist/locale'

data () {
    return {
      en: en,
      es: es
    }
}

<datepicker :language="de"></datepicker>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example you are not returning German, but you are trying to use it.

```
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker'
import {en, de, es} from 'vuejs-datepicker/dist/locale'

data () {
    return {
      en: en,
      es: es,
      de: de
    }
}

<datepicker :language="de"></datepicker>
```